# Smarty+CodeIgniter Performance

Tags: php, codeigniter, smarty

I am working on a social media project and I want to build it using MVC frameworks in PHP. Right now I know CodeIgniter but don't have extensive experience with it and I know its for small footprints, but I have told by some one that using Smarty as templating engine CI can be utilized for larger footprints.

So my question is that should I go by this strategy or try any other framework like laravel or yii2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Templating engine is not a factor in performance issue. Even CI has its own `template parser` but use raw code in view file make your app faster than templating engine. Such as from CI doc

> CodeIgniter does not require you to use this class since using pure PHP in your view pages lets them run a little faster. However, some developers prefer to use a template engine if they work with designers who they feel would find some confusion working with PHP.

However you can use CodeIgniter(CI) for your app whatever the size of your project. Even enterprise level application can be done with CI. If you need huge `API` or another 3rd party web service to design then `laravel` is good.

Comment: thanks bro. I will consider it.